# TYPO3: HMENU not working in foreign language

Tags: localization, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

The footer menu is defined as follows:

```
temp.footerNav = HMENU
temp.footerNav {
  special = userfunction
  special.userFunc = \MyNamespace\Helper->footerNavArray

  wrap = <ul>|</ul>

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        wrap = |
        expAll = 0

        NO = 1
        NO.ATagParams = class="footer-navigation-link"
        NO.stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
        NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="footer-navigation__item">|</li>
        NO.stdWrap.field = title // nav_title
    }
}
```

The array returned by the function `footerNavArray` looks good in both German

```
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'title' => string 'Unternehmen' (length=11)
      '_OVERRIDE_HREF' => string 'de/unternehmen.html' (length=19)
    ...
  ...
```

and English:

```
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'title' => string 'Company' (length=7)
      '_OVERRIDE_HREF' => string 'en/company.html' (length=15)
    ...
  ...
```

The footer menu works perfectly in English (default language), however, the only output I can see on the German page (L=1) is `<ul></ul>`.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can check whether there is a condition that overwrites the footermenu for german.

Comment: Where/how would I do that?

Comment: If you go to the TypoScript Object Browser, you will find all possible conditions at the bottom of the page. If you check a box, the TSOB will show you the values applied with the checked condition. Now go to temp.footerNav and see what's there ...

Comment: Another question: Do you really need a userfunction for that menu? IMHO it is much easier to create a folder that contains shortcuts to the pages ... or use special.list ...

Comment: The TS object lo the same, regardless of whether or not I set the condition `[globalVar = GP:L = 1]`. And yes, I need a custom function because the footer changes depending on where on the site you are (for example, the link "Terms" always links to the respective terms page of the current sub-tree).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the above behaviour was caused by `[FE][hidePagesIfNotTranslatedByDefault] = 1`, which is required by [Solr for TYPO3](http://www.typo3-solr.com/en/solr-for-typo3/) to work correctly in a multi-language site. By adding `'_SAFE' = true` to the menu array, I was finally able to solve the problem:

```
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'title' => string 'Company' (length=7)
      '_OVERRIDE_HREF' => string 'en/company.html' (length=15)
      '_SAFE' => boolean true
    ...
  ...
```

I've found the solution in line 1213 (core version 7.6.2) of `TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\Menu\AbstractMenuContentObject->filterMenuPages()`:

Comment: After hours of testing and searching, your answerd saved my day! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use global env condition for different language.

```
#setup the default language in case of bad L variable
config.sys_language_mode = content_fallback
config.uniqueLinkVars=1
config.sys_language_overlay = 1
config.sys_language_uid = 0
config.language = en
config.linkVars = L
# Spanish language, sys_language.uid = 1
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
config.sys_language_uid = 1
config.language = es
config.locale_all = spanish
[global]
# English language, sys_language.uid = 0
[globalVar = GP:L = 0]
config.sys_language_uid = 0
config.language = en
[global]
```